# Instantaneous forward rate and bond prices

Tags: bond, forward-rate

Let $P(t,T,T+\tau)$ be the time $t$ forward price for a zero coupon bond (ZCB) spanning $[T, T+\tau]$, and $f(t,T)$ be the time $t$ instantaneous forward rate to time $T$. The relationship between the two is given by:

$$P(t,T,T+\tau) = exp \left( - \int_T^{T+\tau} f(t,u) du \right)$$

I want to derive the following result for the price of a ZCB $P(t,T) \equiv P(t,T,T)$ from the previous equation:

$$f(t,T) = - \frac{\partial \ln P(t,T)}{\partial T}$$

My intuition is to first compute the derivative wrt $T$, and then take the limit $\tau \rightarrow 0$:

\begin{align}
- \ln P(t,T,T+\tau) &= \int_T^{T+\tau} f(t,u) du \\
- \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln P(t,T,T+\tau) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \int_T^{T+\tau} f(t,u) du \quad \text{By Liebniz rule} \\
- \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln P(t,T,T+\tau) &= f(t,T+\tau) \frac{\partial}{\partial T} (T+\tau) - f(t,T) \frac{\partial}{\partial T} (T) \\
- \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln P(t,T,T+\tau) &= f(t,T+\tau) - f(t,T) \quad \text{Taking the limit} \\
- \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln P(t,T) &= f(t,T) - f(t,T) = 0
\end{align}

**1) Could you explain why this approach leads to the wrong result?**

Alternatively, first compute the derivative wrt $T+\tau$, and then take the limit $\tau \rightarrow 0$:

\begin{align}
- \ln P(t,T,T+\tau) &= \int_T^{T+\tau} f(t,u) du \\
- \frac{\partial}{\partial (T+\tau)} \ln P(t,T,T+\tau) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial (T+\tau)} \int_T^{T+\tau} f(t,u) du \quad \text{By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus} \\
- \frac{\partial}{\partial (T+\tau)} \ln P(t,T,T+\tau) &= f(t,T+\tau) \quad \text{Taking the limit} \\
- \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln P(t,T) &= f(t,T)
\end{align}

**2) Is this approach correct?**

Comment: If your zero coupon bond spans no time, then its price is 1.0: $\int_T^T f(t,u) du = 0$ and   $exp(-0)=1.0$, hence $P(t,T,T)$ is 1.0 according to your formulae.

Comment: Thanks, but this comment seems unrelated to what I asked.

Comment: The point being that $P(t,T,T)=P(t,T)=1.0$ for all $t$ for all $T$. Therefore its derivative wrt $t$ or $T$ is zero. You have derived the right result and called it wrong.

Comment: Why is P(t,T) = 1? The time t price of a ZCB with maturity at T>t is generally smaller than 1

Comment: Yes that is true, but that is not what your formula expresses. There is something else wrong with it.